# How to split a list in Python without using any libraries like pandas?

Tags: python

I have been trying to split and combine the following list without using any libraries like pandas.

Input list:

```
aa = [(('a', 'b', 'c'), 1), (('x', 'y', 'z'), 5), (('xa', 'ya', 'za'), 25)]
```

Expected output:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c', 1), ('x', 'y', 'z', 5), ('xa', 'ya', 'za', 25)]
```

I have already tried:

```
aa = [inner
    for outer in aa
       for inner in outer]
```

But it gave me:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), 1, ('x', 'y', 'z'), 5, ('xa', 'ya', 'za'), 25]
```

Which is close but not what I am looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [1]: aa = [(('a', 'b', 'c'), 1), (('x', 'y', 'z'), 5),(('xa', 'ya', 'za'), 25)]

In [2]: [(*i[0], i[1]) for i in aa]
Out[2]: [('a', 'b', 'c', 1), ('x', 'y', 'z', 5), ('xa', 'ya', 'za', 25)]
```

`*` operator unpacks tuple items.

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension

```py
aa = [(('a', 'b', 'c'), 1), (('x', 'y', 'z'), 5),(('xa', 'ya', 'za'), 25)]

[(*i[0], i[1])for i in aa] #[('a', 'b', 'c', 1), ('x', 'y', 'z', 5), ('xa', 'ya', 'za', 25)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using the tuple unpacking is to use `+` operator between two tuples:

```py
>>> [v[0]+(v[1],) for v in aa]
[('a', 'b', 'c', 1), ('x', 'y', 'z', 5), ('xa', 'ya', 'za', 25)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
aa = [(('a', 'b', 'c'), 1), (('x', 'y', 'z'), 5), (('xa', 'ya', 'za'), 25)]

aa = [x + (y,) for x,y in aa]
```